# How to Execute Batch File Remotely in java?

Tags: java, sockets, batch-file, ftp, rmi

I have to execute batch file present at remote machine from my local machine.

I am connecting through ftp to remote machine and try to execute batch file remotely.but not able to do that also not getiing any exception .below is my code

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws SocketException, IOException,
        InterruptedException {
static String server = "192.168.2.133";
static int port = 21;
static String user = "kamal";
static String pass = "12345";
static FTPClient ftpClient;

    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    ftpClient = new FTPClient();
    ftpClient.connect(server, port);
    ftpClient.login(user, pass);
    ftpClient.enterLocalPassiveMode();
    ftpClient.changeWorkingDirectory("/");

    System.out.println(ftpClient.isConnected());
    // ftpClient.setFileType(FTP.BINARY_FILE_TYPE);

    System.out.println("ftpClient.printWorkingDirectory() "
            + ftpClient.printWorkingDirectory());

    String[] str = ftpClient.listNames(ftpClient.printWorkingDirectory());
    for (String string : str) {
        System.out.println(string);
    }

    // ftpClient.changeWorkingDirectory(ftpClient.printWorkingDirectory().concat("demo"));
    System.out.println("ftpClient.printWorkingDirectory() "
            + ftpClient.printWorkingDirectory());
    String psCommand = "C:/Users/kamlesh.kumar/Downloads/PSTools/PsExec.exe  //"
            + server + " -u " + user + " -p " + pass;
    psCommand = psCommand + " " + "MEF.bat";
    // psCommand = psCommand + " " + commandToRunOnRemoteMachine + " " +
    // parameters;
    String[] cmd = new String[5];
    cmd[0] = "cmd.exe";
    cmd[1] = "/C";
    cmd[2] = psCommand;
    cmd[3] = "";
    cmd[4] = "";
    // Run remote command
    // ftpClient.changeWorkingDirectory(ftpClient.printWorkingDirectory().concat("\\\\192.168.2.135\\demo\\demo"));
    // System.out.println(ftpClient.printWorkingDirectory());
    File f = new File(ftpClient.printWorkingDirectory());
    Process p = null;
    try {
        p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(cmd, null, f);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println(e.toString());
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    int exitStatus = 0;
    try {
        exitStatus = p.waitFor();
        System.out.println("exitStatus in try " + exitStatus);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println("exitStatus" + exitStatus);
        System.out.println(e.toString());
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        System.out.println("exitStatus in finally " + exitStatus);
    }
    if (exitStatus == 0) {
        System.out.println("Done");

    }

}
```

Comment: You cannot execute file remotely using FTP.  Look at using Microsoft's PSEXEC utility.

Comment: ftp is only for file transfer.Most popular tool for remote execution is PSexec though it has problems when called from [java](http://forum.sysinternals.com/faq-common-pstools-issues_topic15920.html). You can check SCHTASKS or WMIC help to how you can execute remotely a script without third party tools.

Comment: One answer to your question is RMI. You even included it in the tags. Why then are you attempting to use FTP?

Answer (score 0):

You can get PSEXEC from https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/pxexec.aspx and what I have done before was make a batch file that would copy the file you want ran on the remote pc to that PC then use PSEXEC to execute it remotly and also delete that file that was made.  I do not know if that is what you're looking for but it might be sufficient.

```
set remotecpu="computer you're sending it to"

robocopy "localpcdrive\location1\scripts\script you want ran" \\%remotecpu%\c$\temp_folder


psexec \\%remotecpu% -u "username" -p "password" -i -d "C:\temp_folder\path to\script you want ran"
```

And if I am not mistaken that will execute the file for you then just do a del command and remove the temp_folder your script is under. Or use something fancy like

```
If Exist "%SystemDrive%\temp_folder" (RD/S/Q "%SystemDrive%\temp_folder")
```